# Python class substituion with other class?

Tags: python, class, overloading

I have a generic class `UsbLib` which I want to use as a simple clean API. However I want this class to become an other class depending on the circumstances.

```
class UsbLib:

    def __new__(self):
        if this_is_latest_ubuntu():
            return UsbUDisks2() # Doesn't work


class UsbUDisks2(UsbLib):

    def list_devices():
        print("Listing devices..")
```

So for example if I am running the below code in Ubuntu

```
lib=UsbLib()
```

I want it to internally resolve to

```
lib=UsbUDisks2()
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You better do it with some sort of [factory pattern.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern)

In simplest form:

```
def createUsbLib(params):
   if this_is_latest_ubuntu():
      return UsbUDisks2()
   else:
      return UsbLib()
```

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for something called Factory pattern.
In simple terms, you do not instantiate the classes directly, but rather call a function which does the logic and returns the right class/object to you for use.

```
def factory_function():
   if(something):
       return Class1()
   else:
       return Class2()



CC = factory_function()

...
...
```

Or even nicer, use a common parent and use a static method in that parent to get the right child

```
class ClassFather:
   @staticmethod
   def factory():
      if(something):
         return Class1()
      else:
         return Class2()


class Class1(ClassFather): # not really necessary to have inheritance, only if common functionality
   pass 

class Class2(ClassFather): # not really necessary to have inheritance, only if common functionality
   pass
```